# rsync warning: some files vanished before they could be transferred (code 24) at main.c(1196) [sender=3.1.2]

Tags: linux, резервное-копирование, rsync

По завершению симуляции резервного копирования через `rsync`:

```
rsync -r -n -t -v --progress -s / /home/wolf
```

Я получаю ошибку *Rsync process exit status: 24* , а точнее :

```
file has vanished: "/proc/10/exe"
file has vanished: "/proc/10/task/10/exe"
file has vanished: "/proc/1042/exe"
file has vanished: "/proc/1042/task/1042/exe"
file has vanished: "/proc/106/exe"
file has vanished: "/proc/106/task/106/exe"
file has vanished: "/proc/108/exe"
file has vanished: "/proc/108/task/108/exe"
file has vanished: "/proc/11/exe"
file has vanished: "/proc/11/task/11/exe"
file has vanished: "/proc/12/exe"
file has vanished: "/proc/12/task/12/exe"
file has vanished: "/proc/13/exe"
file has vanished: "/proc/13/task/13/exe"
file has vanished: "/proc/14/exe"
file has vanished: "/proc/14/task/14/exe"
file has vanished: "/proc/15/exe"
file has vanished: "/proc/15/task/15/exe"
file has vanished: "/proc/16/exe"
file has vanished: "/proc/16/task/16/exe"
file has vanished: "/proc/1645/exe"
file has vanished: "/proc/1645/task/1645/exe"
file has vanished: "/proc/169/exe"
file has vanished: "/proc/169/task/169/exe"
file has vanished: "/proc/170/exe"
file has vanished: "/proc/170/task/170/exe"
file has vanished: "/proc/171/exe"
file has vanished: "/proc/171/task/171/exe"
file has vanished: "/proc/172/exe"
file has vanished: "/proc/172/task/172/exe"
file has vanished: "/proc/176/exe"
file has vanished: "/proc/176/task/176/exe"
file has vanished: "/proc/177/exe"
file has vanished: "/proc/177/task/177/exe"
file has vanished: "/proc/178/exe"
file has vanished: "/proc/178/task/178/exe"
file has vanished: "/proc/179/exe"
file has vanished: "/proc/179/task/179/exe"
file has vanished: "/proc/185/exe"
file has vanished: "/proc/185/task/185/exe"
file has vanished: "/proc/186/exe"
file has vanished: "/proc/186/task/186/exe"
file has vanished: "/proc/187/exe"
file has vanished: "/proc/187/task/187/exe"
file has vanished: "/proc/19/exe"
file has vanished: "/proc/19/task/19/exe"
directory has vanished: "/proc/1901/task/4179"
file has vanished: "/proc/2/exe"
file has vanished: "/proc/2/task/2/exe"
file has vanished: "/proc/20/exe"
file has vanished: "/proc/20/task/20/exe"
file has vanished: "/proc/21/exe"
file has vanished: "/proc/21/task/21/exe"
file has vanished: "/proc/22/exe"
file has vanished: "/proc/22/task/22/exe"
file has vanished: "/proc/226/exe"
file has vanished: "/proc/226/task/226/exe"
file has vanished: "/proc/2261/exe"
file has vanished: "/proc/2261/task/2261/exe"
file has vanished: "/proc/228/exe"
file has vanished: "/proc/228/task/228/exe"
file has vanished: "/proc/229/exe"
file has vanished: "/proc/229/task/229/exe"
file has vanished: "/proc/24/exe"
file has vanished: "/proc/24/task/24/exe"
file has vanished: "/proc/2497/exe"
file has vanished: "/proc/2497/task/2497/exe"
file has vanished: "/proc/25/exe"
file has vanished: "/proc/25/task/25/exe"
file has vanished: "/proc/26/exe"
file has vanished: "/proc/26/task/26/exe"
file has vanished: "/proc/27/exe"
file has vanished: "/proc/27/task/27/exe"
file has vanished: "/proc/273/exe"
file has vanished: "/proc/273/task/273/exe"
file has vanished: "/proc/274/exe"
file has vanished: "/proc/274/task/274/exe"
file has vanished: "/proc/2787/exe"
file has vanished: "/proc/2787/task/2787/exe"
file has vanished: "/proc/28/exe"
file has vanished: "/proc/28/task/28/exe"
file has vanished: "/proc/2838/exe"
file has vanished: "/proc/2838/task/2838/exe"
file has vanished: "/proc/2853/exe"
file has vanished: "/proc/2853/task/2853/exe"
file has vanished: "/proc/2861/exe"
file has vanished: "/proc/2861/task/2861/exe"
file has vanished: "/proc/30/exe"
file has vanished: "/proc/30/task/30/exe"
file has vanished: "/proc/31/exe"
file has vanished: "/proc/31/task/31/exe"
file has vanished: "/proc/313/exe"
file has vanished: "/proc/313/task/313/exe"
file has vanished: "/proc/32/exe"
file has vanished: "/proc/32/task/32/exe"
file has vanished: "/proc/33/exe"
file has vanished: "/proc/33/task/33/exe"
file has vanished: "/proc/333/exe"
file has vanished: "/proc/333/task/333/exe"
file has vanished: "/proc/36/exe"
file has vanished: "/proc/36/task/36/exe"
file has vanished: "/proc/37/exe"
file has vanished: "/proc/37/task/37/exe"
file has vanished: "/proc/38/exe"
file has vanished: "/proc/38/task/38/exe"
file has vanished: "/proc/3883/exe"
file has vanished: "/proc/3883/task/3883/exe"
file has vanished: "/proc/3886/exe"
file has vanished: "/proc/3886/task/3886/exe"
file has vanished: "/proc/39/exe"
file has vanished: "/proc/39/task/39/exe"
file has vanished: "/proc/4/exe"
file has vanished: "/proc/4/task/4/exe"
file has vanished: "/proc/40/exe"
file has vanished: "/proc/40/task/40/exe"
file has vanished: "/proc/41/exe"
file has vanished: "/proc/41/task/41/exe"
file has vanished: "/proc/42/exe"
file has vanished: "/proc/42/task/42/exe"
file has vanished: "/proc/43/exe"
file has vanished: "/proc/43/task/43/exe"
file has vanished: "/proc/44/exe"
file has vanished: "/proc/44/task/44/exe"
file has vanished: "/proc/446/exe"
file has vanished: "/proc/446/task/446/exe"
file has vanished: "/proc/46/exe"
file has vanished: "/proc/46/task/46/exe"
file has vanished: "/proc/47/exe"
file has vanished: "/proc/47/task/47/exe"
file has vanished: "/proc/48/exe"
file has vanished: "/proc/48/task/48/exe"
file has vanished: "/proc/482/exe"
file has vanished: "/proc/482/task/482/exe"
file has vanished: "/proc/483/exe"
file has vanished: "/proc/483/task/483/exe"
file has vanished: "/proc/49/exe"
file has vanished: "/proc/49/task/49/exe"
file has vanished: "/proc/50/exe"
file has vanished: "/proc/50/task/50/exe"
file has vanished: "/proc/6/exe"
file has vanished: "/proc/6/task/6/exe"
file has vanished: "/proc/64/exe"
file has vanished: "/proc/64/task/64/exe"
file has vanished: "/proc/65/exe"
file has vanished: "/proc/65/task/65/exe"
file has vanished: "/proc/7/exe"
file has vanished: "/proc/7/task/7/exe"
file has vanished: "/proc/8/exe"
file has vanished: "/proc/8/task/8/exe"
file has vanished: "/proc/9/exe"
file has vanished: "/proc/9/task/9/exe"
rsync warning: some files vanished before they could be transferred (code 24) at main.c(1196) [sender=3.1.2]
Rsync process exit status: 24
```

Вопросы :
 1. Почему это происходит ?
 2. Стоит ли на эту ошибку реагировать или можно продолжить бэкапить ?
 3. Исходя из второго пункта, можно ли такой бэкап использовать для восстановления системы ?

Comment: Я бы копирование делал rdiff-backup. И не всей системы, а только нужных файлов и `/etc`. Какой смысл харнить `/bin`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Файлы в каталогах /proc и /sys не являются нормальными файлами, они виртуальные, представляющие собой интерфейс с ядром. В связи с этим они могут изменяться при каждом чтении. У rsync'а едет крыша, когда он видит, что файлы под ним меняются.

Просто исключите каталоги /proc и /sys из бекапа.